# React detect variable change across many files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, pass-by-reference, self-modifying

I have a global variable on my reducer (Redux) code which is a array of objects that contains the data.

I'm constantly passing that variable across multiple files (view files) using connect from React Redux like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { appointments } = state.Appointment;
    return {
        appointments
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    /* Some methods */
})(Appointment);
```

When I want to modify a specific element of that array, I pass the reference of that element so I later won't have to deal with replacements. The problem is that someone (a view) is modifying that reference and it's changing it from an Object to a Number type. Is their a easy way such a PropTypes (in the reducer file) to detect who is changing the reference of that array position from an Object to a Number?

Thanks

Comment: Im not sure that Im getting what you're saying. are you saying that a component is mutating an array item (by reference I get it) inside a container and not in the reducer itself?

Comment: Yes the element is mutating. The array is inside the reducer file which is recieved as props

Comment: yes. but thats not the 'Redux' way to do things. Containers should never directly mutate store values. Only the reducer (via actions). thats what its for.  that way there is a single source of data to observe. once you correct that. and updating props is definitely  not  the React way to do things.By definition Props are read only. I think you need to reevaluate your approach. If you want to change data, either use state and manipulate it as you want or do it in the reducer and pass it down to the components with mapStateToProps/ selectors

Comment: Ok so I managed to follow your advice and map my props pass from the reducer to a state variable which get updated using setState. Does it matter that I do any logic inside a Reducer file instead of the action file?

Comment: Well they both have different purposes. The Reducer's job is to set the state for that flow, meaning it handles updating the store. the Action file's job is performing actions and bridging the Component with the reducer. They both do different things. Reducer should not carry a lot of logic, but handle the setting of the state. think of it like so, you perform some action, after which you want to update your state in order to maintain the state changes. If you dont want to carry the state changes then you can just use your "local" state and use the setState

Comment: So in your example. if you want that data to be stored in the store, you should only set it via the reducer, (action might perform certain actions upon it first). if you don't care about that data in other flows and its only for your 'local' state. then use the component state and store the data there. either way the data always should flow in one direction.

Comment: you can of course always refer to the docs:https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers they are very useful for those purposes.

Comment: Ok thanks I will take a look at it. It seems I will have to write the logic and hopefully I will find the mistake